# Run multiple virtual Android system parallel

Tags: android, sdk, virtual, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

Hey I need to run multiple emulations of Andriod so I can run them simultaneously. Is it possible to run multiple virtual devices with AVD manager from Android SDK? If yes how stable is it? Its important that I have a good uptime with all devices. Are there any experiences in this context out there?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Emulators use a lot of resources, so having more than one running at one time will cause both to lag and stutter. Emulators are not good for longevity tests, either.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple emulations can be run on the system if your system supports the heavy hardware requirement. Each emulated device manages it's own session and is reliable until the software halts or due to insufficient hardware resources.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since the need of heavy hardware, a server could fulfill the requirements right? Can  you also tell me somethhing about that? Usually,  when I  rent a server this is a emulation itself right? Are there  any trouble if I want a "nested" emulation with android? One more thing, since I want to run a automated script with Appium I think I could also use a headless Android  emulation. This  would heavily decrease the workload right?